# Can not connect(bridge) any database with "docker-compose"

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

cannnot connect database on "docker-compose"

Hi there.

I trying connect to database but can not conected.

Could you tell me some tips for resoleve these isssue?

> docker -v

- Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea

> docker-compose -v

- docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a

> OS

- Centos8

I'm trying to launch redmine , so I take the "docker-compose.yml" from bitnami's github repo

https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redmine

and run this command

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redmine/master/docker-compose.yml > docker-compose.yml
```

and check the file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.3'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_redmine
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_redmine
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami'
  redmine:
    image: 'bitnami/redmine:latest'
    environment:
      - REDMINE_DB_USERNAME=bn_redmine
      - REDMINE_DB_NAME=bitnami_redmine
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    volumes:
      - 'redmine_data:/bitnami'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  redmine_data:
    driver: local
```

it looks fine so I run below.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

and wait few min and check the log with this command.

```
docker-compose logs
```

it show this log . It say "Error executing 'postInstallation': Failed to connect to mariadb:3306 after 36 tries".

```
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:19.39
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:19.40 Welcome to the Bitnami mariadb container
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:19.40 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:19.40 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb/issues
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:19.40 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:19.40
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:19.40 INFO  ==> ** Starting MariaDB setup **
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:19.44 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:19.44 WARN  ==> You set the environment variable ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes. For safety reasons, do not use this flag in a production environment.
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:19.48 INFO  ==> Initializing mariadb database
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:19.51 INFO  ==> Installing database
redmine_1  |
redmine_1  | Welcome to the Bitnami redmine container
redmine_1  | Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redmine
redmine_1  | Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redmine/issues
redmine_1  | Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
redmine_1  |
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:23.05 INFO  ==> Starting mariadb in background
redmine_1  | nami    INFO  Initializing redmine
redmine_1  | redmine INFO  Configuring Redmine database...
redmine_1  | mysql-c INFO  Trying to connect to MySQL server
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:24.12 INFO  ==> Configuring authentication
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:24.17 INFO  ==> Running mysql_upgrade
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:24.35 INFO  ==> Stopping mariadb
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:26.38 INFO  ==> ** MariaDB setup finished! **
mariadb_1  |
mariadb_1  | mariadb 05:22:26.42 INFO  ==> ** Starting MariaDB **
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] /opt/bitnami/mariadb/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.22-MariaDB) starting as process 1 ...
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.22 started; log sequence number 1625457; transaction id 21
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /bitnami/mariadb/data/ib_buffer_pool
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200206  5:22:26
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@1643f97fe62c' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
mariadb_1  | 2020-02-06  5:22:26 0 [Note] /opt/bitnami/mariadb/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
mariadb_1  | Version: '10.3.22-MariaDB'  socket: '/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
redmine_1  | Error executing 'postInstallation': Failed to connect to mariadb:3306 after 36 tries
redmine_redmine_1 exited with code 1
```

It looks like database issue , so I was try access this instance and try to connect mariadb.

It was work and could see databases.

```
docker exec -it <mariadb's ID> /bin/bash
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I have no name!@c97be876fcf9:/$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 9
Server version: 10.3.22-MariaDB Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| bitnami_redmine    |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

So I think it is port issue and I add option that use specific port 3306 and open 3306 port in host machine.

```
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
```

still not working.

Then I think try another "docker-compose.yml" .

so try create new docker-compose.yml

```
docker-compose down -v

rm -rf docker-compose.yml

vi docker-compose.yml
```

and add this argument

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
~
```

this use WordPress and MySQL it is different that I use before.

But it not working.

Could access WordPress's website but can not connect database.

So I think these problem is can not bridge each container  correctly especially application to database container.

But I have no idea what should try.

Some one have tips please tell me the your knowledge.

Best regards.

ps 2020-02-07
I tried

```
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl restart docker
```

and it worked.

It looks like firewall issue.
But still　
I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: addition:These "docker-compose.yml"  worked on "docker for windows"

Comment: and Centos8 is mounted on VPS

Answer (score 1):

I resolve that issue!!!

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
systemctl restart docker
```

if not work that try this.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-port=4243/tcp

firewall-cmd --reload
systemctl restart docker
```